# Using Nodejs to make POST request to Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I'm making a POST request after a successful GET request with NodeJS, I am getting the crumb successfully from Jenkins but I am always getting the same response from Jenkins "No valid crumb was included in the request", can someone help me where I might be missing it here?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');

//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.status('404').send('Not Found');
});

app.post('/process',function(req,res){

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    '--user':       'username',
    '--password':     'password'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://10.20.1.195:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var crumb = body; //Jenkins-Crumb:aa7d8b4c316415779703a04a99b85c50
        var headers = { crumb }
        // Configure the request
        var options = {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/job/Nightwatch/buildWithParameters',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            qs: {'TOKEN': 'special-token', 'PROJECT': req.body.project, 'CATEGORY': req.body.category, 'URL': req.body.staginUrl}
        }

        // Start the request
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // Print out the response body
                console.log(body)
            } else {
                console.log(response.statusMessage)
            }
        })

    } else {
        console.log('Could not get crumb from Jenkins! Check NodeJS Server')
    }
})

res.end('Complete');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Including Auth Token(generated from inside Jenkins security tab) does the job. Include that as Basic Auth i.e. userid and password=token. That should work.

Answer (score -2):

Please check this issue ticket.

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2067

This will solve problem.

Comment: I have looked at that, what exactly are you pointing out? I am using NodeJs not wget, cURL, python or Ruby. Are you suggesting I turn off the security? I don't want to do that.